# "-bereich" in context

Tags: standard-german

What do the various uses of "-bereich" mean in the text below? Are these words (and uses) restricted to any particular register or context? Neither Duden, nor Google Translate have provided any adequate definitions. (Ironically, this is a Duden provided for "auf.")

> zur Angabe der Richtung; bezieht sich auf eine Stelle, Oberfläche, auf einen Erstreckungsbereich, einen Zielpunkt o. Ä., bezeichnet den Gang zu einem/in einen Raum, zu einem/in ein Gebäude; gibt die Richtung in einem Seins-, Tätigkeitsbereich o. Ä. an

Comment: Since these are just compound nouns: did you look up "_Bereich_" already? Could you please explain, in what way the findings aren't satisfactory?

Answer (score 1):

**Bereich** simply means *area* or *scope*.

You won't find words as *Erstreckungsbereich* or *Seinsbereich* in any dictionary, as they are made up from scratch.

It's the German way of saying *the area of "Erstreckung"* or *the area of "Sein"*.

Comment: I understand that but in the context of "Erstreckungsbereich" and "Tätigkeitsbereich" in particular, what do the compounds mean? As I understand it, "Erstreckung" means extension. So does "auf einen Erstreckungsbereich" mean "into an extension-area"? And what does "gibt die Richtung in einem Seins-, Tätigkeitsbereich o. Ä. an" mean?

Comment: "You won't find words as[sic] Erstreckungsbereich or Seinsbereich in any dictionary". AFAIK, they were taken from the [**Duden** description of the word *auf*](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/auf_Praeposition) --> 1.b. That is a dictionary, isn't it?

Comment: Well, it's not explained in there.

Comment: *Erstreckung* does not mean *extension*, but *extent*. So it's the area of extent or scope of extent. Example: Auf einen Hektar kommt ein Traktor.

Comment: *gibt die Richtung in einem Seins-, Tätigkeitsbereich o. Ä. an* – explains the direction inside the scope of being or doing.